# I'm tyring to use \i on PSQL on Windows

Tags: sql, psql

I'm trying to execute commands from a file doing the following

```
\i C:\Users\nick-\Downloads\person.sql
```

and am getting this back

```
C:: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I not following the correct file path or is there some other issue that's likely?

Comment: Try `\i c:/Users/nick-/Downloads/person.sql`

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\i c:/Users/nick-/Downloads/person.sql` worked

Answer (score 0):

\i 'c:/path with spaces/file.sql'